# what is the easiest way to solve the indefinite integral in R

Tags: r

Suppose i have integral

```
Integral(x^2*sin(x), (x, 0, 1))
```

I can self solve it manually.

```
1.The answer in formula
```

[image]

2.or or in numerical form `=0.223244275483933`

3.or can write it so
[image]

and plot i think will be something like that
[image]

So my question. What there is way in R solve indefinite integrals to get answer by formula and in numerical form , like i get when solve it manually, and get the plot?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the symbolic integration, you can use the `Ryacas` package. A basic function to draw both a function and its integral, with appropriate labels, would be something like this:

```r
library(Ryacas)
library(ggplot2)

plot_integral <- function(f, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 2)) {
  
  x <- yac_symbol('x')
  
  integral <- as_r(do.call(integrate, list(f = body(f), var = x)))
  
  fdx <- as.function(list(x = NULL, str2lang(as.character(integral))))
  
  f_lab <- as.character(as.expression(body(f)))
  fdx_lab <- as.character(as.expression(body(fdx)))
  
  ggplot() +
    geom_function(fun = f, mapping = aes(colour = 'function')) +
    geom_function(fun = fdx, mapping = aes(color = 'integral')) +
    lims(x = xlim, y = ylim) +
    geom_label(aes(x = 0.5, y = f(0.5)), label = f_lab, parse = TRUE) +
    geom_label(aes(x = 0.5, y = fdx(0.5)), label = fdx_lab, parse = TRUE) +
    theme_minimal()
}
```

And all you need to do is pass it a function of x, which it will integrate symbolically, plot, and label:

```r
plot_integral(function(x) cos(x))
```

[image]

```r
plot_integral(function(x) exp(2 * x), ylim = c(0, 10))
```

[image]

```r
plot_integral(function(x) sin(x) + cos(x), ylim = c(-2, 2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Will the `integrate` function suit your needs for the numerical answer?

```r
my_fun = function(x) {
  x^2*sin(x)
}

integrate(f = my_fun, lower = 0, upper = 1)
#> 0.2232443 with absolute error < 2.5e-15
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>